# How to get details(like username, password, host IQN) of an already authorized Virtual Machine and storage target address through REST API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am new for Softlayer. I need details of Authorized host(Virtual Machine) like username, password, hostIQN and Storage target Address through REST API. So could you kindly provide the information to me.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example that show you: “Username”, “Password”, “Host IQN” for authorized hosts (Bare Metal Server, Virtual Server, IP Address).

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,username,allowedVirtualGuests[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedHardware[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedIpAddresses[ipAddress,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]]]

Method: GET
```

To get the `target address`, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apieky]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_Id]/getNetworkConnectionDetails

Method: GET
```

**Reference:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getNetworkConnectionDetails](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getNetworkConnectionDetails)

Comment: Kind of sucks you have to make a second call to get something so essential as the target address for ISCSI.